# Cmake undefined reference to `boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_short_string() const'

Tags: c++, boost

I spend whole day trying to  link the `data_time` library to my c++ `cmake` project.

So I am using `cmake 3.4` and `boost 1.61.0`. 
I have the class where is a function which is taking local time:

```
void TestClass::getTime() {
    this->endDate = boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time();
}
```

Then I want to return the value of `endDate` by function returning string:

```
string testCalss::Info() {
   return to_simple_string(this->beginningDate);   
}
```

I need to convert the type of `endDate` variable to `string`, because function is string type.

I am getting error messages while program is linking:

```
In function boost::date_time::month_formatter<boost::gregorian::greg_month, boost::date_time::simple_format<char>, char>::format_month(boost::gregorian::greg_month const&, std::ostream&)':
/usr/include/boost/date_time/date_formatting.hpp:44: undefined reference to `boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_short_string() const'
/usr/include/boost/date_time/date_formatting.hpp:49: undefined reference to `boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_long_string() const'
```

I have read that data_time is not only header-only library and I should build and add it to my project.

I have tried this command `gcc myapp.cpp -omyapp -lboost_date_time`, and it's does not work because I am using `g++` in `cmake` project and I haven't find nothing for g++.

I also tried this:

```
c++ -I path/to/boost_1_61_0 example.cpp -o example \
   ~/boost/stage/lib/libboost_regex-gcc34-mt-d-1_36.a
```

Its example from official boost docs how to link libraries. 
In `cmake` project I have few `cpp` files. Should I run this command using file where is my converting command?

Is there any easier way to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to solve the problem. The way I choose is simple. First of all I have used the `locate */boost/date_time*` command to find where is my `boost` and `date_time` libraries installed. I did not know what version of boost library I am using, so I used `locate` command again to find `boost/version.hpp` file. After that I added few lines to my `CmakeLists.txt`:

```
find_package( Boost 1.60.0 COMPONENTS date_time)
if(Boost_FOUND)
      include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
      target_link_libraries( Program ${Boost_DATE_TIME_LIBRARY} )
endif()
```

Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(boost_ptime)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

add_executable(boost_ptime ${SOURCE_FILES})

find_package( Boost 1.73 COMPONENTS date_time)
if(Boost_FOUND)
      include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
      target_link_libraries( boost_ptime ${Boost_DATE_TIME_LIBRARY} )
endif()
```

Thanks to Warszawski Koks, I was able to compile my program in this way. Above is the full CMakeLists.txt file.